# Given n points randomly distributed in a square, find the area taken by each

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

Given n points randomly distributed in [0,1] × [0,1], I try to allot to each point the area of the points which are closest to that point.

More formally as follows:

Given n points (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>n</sub>) in [0,1] × [0,1], assign to each x<sub>j</sub> a value equal to the measure of the set of points { z | d(z, x<sub>j</sub>) ≤ d(z, x<sub>i</sub>) } for all i in (1, 2, .. n).

I can't come up with anything remotely efficient. Any help?

Comment: It may be better to ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com...

Comment: The phrase "measure of the set" isn't clear to me.  Indeed, I think the entire third paragraph is a bit dense.  You might want to give a concrete example of an input and the intended output to help people along.

Comment: Looks like you want a vornoi diagram of the points, and use the area of the vornoi cells.

Comment: [Measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29) of any finite point set is zero, unless you are talking about some non-standard notion of measure, so you ought to define it first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Fortune's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm) for generating [Voronoi diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

[image: Fortune's algorithm]

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

You may want to try using a KD tree.

Comment: fair enough. I've added a link to a KD Tree.